# Unformat disk size strings

Tags: string, bash

Is there some way to convert strings like `1K` to `1000`, `1M` to `1000000` etc. with a single Bash command? I'd like to avoid being the one million and thirty-first guy to create a >10-line or >100-character one-liner hack for this. Something like `iso2int 5MB`.

Edit: `units -t '5MB' 'bytes` works, but that tool is not available. Are there any simple ways to convert *either* `5M` or `5MB` and similar to bytes?

max's solution was elegant, but the shortest equivalent which would work in my case is at the very least `sed -e 's/b//i;s/k/*1000/i;s/m/*1000000/i;s/g/*1000000000/i;s/t/*1000000000000/i' | bc`.

Comment: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/perl-vs-bash-code-number-of-lines-534142/

Comment: That's converting the wrong way.

Comment: It's not exactly hard to change it...

Comment: you can make it a little bit shorter: sed -e 's/t/kg/i;s/g/km/i;s/m/kk/i;s/k/*1000/ig;s/b//i' | bc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$ echo "1K + 10M" | sed -e "s/K/*1024/g;s/M/*1024*1024/" | bc
10486784
```

Edit:

```
sed -e 's/t/kg/i;s/g/km/i;s/m/kk/i;s/k/*1000/ig;s/b//i' | bc
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

My original answer is just ***silly***. Here is a pure Bash solution based on [max taldykin's `sed`/`bc` excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4399475/unformat-disk-size-strings/4399605#4399605).

```
s=21TB;(( $BASH_VERSINFO >= 4 ))&&s=${s^^};s=${s/B};s=${s/E/KP};s=${s/P/KT}; s=${s/T/KG};s=${s/G/KM};s=${s/M/KK};s=${s//K/*1024};printf "%'u\n" $((s))
```

This is longer than my original one-liner only by virtue of the fact that it includes case-insensitivity while the latter didn't (although it could and the function did). It's only about twice as long by character count as max's when adjusted for equivalent functionality.

**Original:**

Here is a pure Bash solution:

As a function (see below for a one-liner):

```
#!/bin/bash
# written by Dennis Williamson 2010-12-09
# for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4399475/unformat-disk-size-strings
expandsi () {
    # set k to 1000 if that's your preference, p is a pattern to match unit chars
    local k=1024 p='E|P|T|G|M|K| '   # exa, peta, tera, giga, mega, kilo, bytes
    local b=$1 c e s=${p//|}         # s is the list of units
    (( $BASH_VERSINFO >= 4 )) && b=${b^^}  # toupper for case insensitivity
    b=${b%B*}                        # strip any trailing B from the input
    c=${b: -1}                       # get the unit character
    c=${c/%!($p)/ }                  # add a space if there's no unit char
    b=${b%@($p)*}                    # remove the unit character
    e=${s#*${c:0:1}}                 # index into the list of units
    # do the math, remove the single quote to omit the thousands separator
    printf "%'u\n" $((b * k**${#e}))
}
```

To test the function:

```
testvals='1 22 333 4444 '
testvals+='4B 44B 1000B '
testvals+='1M 1MB 987MB '
testvals+='1K 23KB 1KB 100K '
testvals+='10G 10GB 3333G '
testvals+='3T 12PB '
# exabytes is pushing it for Bash's int capacity
# on my system, printf "%'u\n" -1 gives 18,446,744,073,709,551,615
testvals+='15EB '

for i in $testvals
do
    expandsi $i
done
```

Results:

```
1
22
333
4,444
4
44
1,000
1,048,576
1,048,576
1,034,944,512
1,024
23,552
1,024
102,400
10,737,418,240
10,737,418,240
3,578,781,499,392
3,298,534,883,328
13,510,798,882,111,488
17,293,822,569,102,704,640
```

As promised, at long last, the one-liner version:

```
$ b=200GB k=1024 p='E|P|T|G|M|K| ';s=${p//|} b=${b%B*};c=${b: -1};c=${c/%!($p)/ };b=${b%@($p)*};e=${s#*${c:0:1}};printf "%'u\n" $((b * k**${#e}))
214,748,364,800
```